# What are the advantages of SoundPool's load method that takes offset and length parameters?

Tags: android

I am intrigued by the `SoundPool.load(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length, int priority)` method in the Android API. Does it exist just as a convenience for people that were already storing audio this way? Does it do anything for performance?

Answer (score 0):

In game development there are sprite sheets - a big images with lots of animation frames. Have a look at this [example](http://gamesprite.files.wordpress.com/2008/01/iris.gif). Advantage of storing sprites on a big sheet is that you have to load it to memory only once, and show only the particular part of it with needed frame, because disk operations are expensive.
I think the method you are asking about has the same purpose, but applied to sounds. So when you have lots of short sounds you can concatenate them into one file and play only needed part of it.